# How can I display multiple images in a loop in a WP7 app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, loops, windows-phone-7

In my (Silverlight) weather app I am downloading up to 6 seperate weather radar images (each one taken about 20 mins apart) from a web site and what I need to do is display each image for a second then at the end of the loop, pause 2 seconds then start the loop again.  (This means the loop of images will play until the user clicks the back or home button which is what I want.)

So, I have a RadarImage class as follows, and each image is getting downloaded (via WebClient) and then loaded into a instance of RadarImage which is then added to a collection (ie: `List<RadarImage>`)...

```
//Following code is in my radar.xaml.cs to download the images....
int  imagesToDownload = 6;
int imagesDownloaded = 0;
RadarImage rdr    = new RadarImage(<image url>);    //this happens in a loop of image URLs
rdr.FileCompleteEvent += ImageDownloadedEventHandler;

//This code in a class library.
public class RadarImage
{
    public int ImageIndex;
    public string ImageURL;
    public DateTime ImageTime;
    public Boolean Downloaded;
    public BitmapImage Bitmap;

    private WebClient client;

    public delegate void FileCompleteHandler(object sender);
    public event FileCompleteHandler FileCompleteEvent; 

    public RadarImage(int index, string imageURL)
    {
        this.ImageIndex = index;
        this.ImageURL = imageURL;

        //...other code here to load in datetime properties etc...

        client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(this.ImageURL, UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    private void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            StreamResourceInfo sri = new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result as Stream, null);
            this.Bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            this.Bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
            this.Downloaded = true;
            FileCompleteEvent(this);         //Fire the event to let the app page know to add it to it's List<RadarImage> collection
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the class above I have exposed an event handler to let my app page know when each image has downloaded.  When they have all downloaded I then run the following code in my xaml page - but only the last image ever shows up and I can't work out why!

```
    private void ImageDownloadedEventHandler(object sender)
    {
        imagesDownloaded++;
        if (imagesDownloaded == imagesToDownload)
        {
            AllImagesDownloaded = true;

            DisplayRadarImages();
        }
    }

    private void DisplayRadarImages()
    {
        TimerSingleton.Timer.Stop();

        foreach (RadarImage img in radarImages)
        {
            imgRadar.Source = img.Bitmap;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        TimerSingleton.Timer.Start();   //Tick poroperty is set to 2000 milliseconds
    }

    private void SingleTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRadarImages();
    }
```

So you can see  that I have a static instance of a timer class which is stopped (if running), then the loop should show each image for a second. When all 6 have been displayed then it pauses, the timer starts and after two seconds DisplayRadarImages() gets called again.

But as I said before, I can only ever get the last image to show for some reason and I can't seem to get this working properly.

I'm fairly new to WP7 development (though not to .Net) so just wondering how best to do this - I was thinking of trying this with a web browser control but surely there must be a more elegant way to loop through a bunch of images!

Sorry this is so long but any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Mike

Comment: FYI WP7 use Silverlight (based on version 3) which is a superset of a subset of WPF. THis is not the smae as WPF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a background thread with either a Timer or Sleep to periodically update your image control.

[Phạm Tiểu Giao - Threads in WP7](http://my.opera.com/phamtieugiao/blog/2010/10/10/threads-in-wp7)

You'll need to dispatch updates to the UI with

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => { /*  your UI code */ } );
```

Comment: Thanks Mick - I'll try this and see how it goes. You don't have any code that would demonstrate doing that do you?  (The article is useful but doesn't seem to cover this specifically.... will google it as well obviously).

Comment: No worries. I haven't seen source that does exactly what you're trying to do posted, however I have in my own code verified it's fairly straight forward to introduce a sleep in the work event handler between display updates, and in fact the link above uses one too.

Comment: I did get it working with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke exactly the way you suggested Hinek, so thanks for that - but also thanks to Mick N as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add the last image twice to radarImages, set the Timer to 1000 and display just one image on each tick?

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but the delay between loops is not the problem - it's the fact that only the last frame ever appears.

Comment: Yes, I understood this, but the other frames do not appear, because the change is not dispatched. So you have to choices: a) call the Dispatcher manually (Dispatcher.BeginInvoke) or b) return from your method, so the phone does the dispatching manually.

Comment: Sorry Hinek, I misunderstood your answer - I haven't got back to that problem yet as I've been on holiday but will do this weekend so will try your way and also Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.